# Why cant i implement NProgress in my Next.js App?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I think i've followed all the steps necessary for implementing nprogress package. The loading bar shows up when route is changed but nprogress fails to do so. I have tried other ways to implement by using the link to the stylesheet from cdn.js but it did not work then too.

```
    import Loader from "../comps/Loader";
    import Router from "next/router";
    import NProgress from "nprogress";
    import "../styles/globals.css";
    import "../styles/nprogress.css";


const MyApp = ({ Component, pageProps }) => {
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);

  Router.onRouteChangeStart = (url) => {
  

    NProgress.start();
    setIsLoading(true);
  };

  Router.onRouteChangeComplete = () => {
    NProgress.done();
    setIsLoading(false);
  };

  Router.onRouteChangeError = () => {
    NProgress.done();
    setIsLoading(false);
  };
  console.log(isLoading);

  return (
    <>
      
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <Layout>
          {isLoading ? <Loader></Loader> : <Component {...pageProps} />}
        </Layout>
      </ThemeProvider>
    </>
  );
};

export default MyApp;
```

i have also created the mandatory css file

```
#nprogress {
  pointer-events: none;
}

#nprogress .bar {
  background: #e91e63;

  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1031;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;

  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
}

/* Fancy blur effect */
#nprogress .peg {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px #29d, 0 0 5px #29d;
  opacity: 1.0;

  -webkit-transform: rotate(3deg) translate(0px, -4px);
      -ms-transform: rotate(3deg) translate(0px, -4px);
          transform: rotate(3deg) translate(0px, -4px);
}

/* Remove these to get rid of the spinner */
#nprogress .spinner {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1031;
  top: 15px;
  right: 15px;
}

#nprogress .spinner-icon {
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  box-sizing: border-box;

  border: solid 2px transparent;
  border-top-color: #29d;
  border-left-color: #29d;
  border-radius: 50%;

  -webkit-animation: nprogress-spinner 400ms linear infinite;
          animation: nprogress-spinner 400ms linear infinite;
}

.nprogress-custom-parent {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.nprogress-custom-parent #nprogress .spinner,
.nprogress-custom-parent #nprogress .bar {
  position: absolute;
}

@-webkit-keyframes nprogress-spinner {
  0%   { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
@keyframes nprogress-spinner {
  0%   { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order for `NProgress` truly function, it must know the route is changing and have a key for that specific route to handle the component mounting and animation. So it is not needed to do the conditional display of the Loading Component, `NProgress` do it under the hood by `NProgress.start()` and `NProgress.done()`.

_app.js

```js
import Layout from '../components/Layout';
import '../styles/globals.css'
import App from 'next/app'

import NProgress from "nprogress"
import Router, { useRouter } from "next/router"

Router.onRouteChangeStart = url => {
  NProgress.start()
}

Router.onRouteChangeComplete = () => NProgress.done()

Router.onRouteChangeError = () => NProgress.done()
function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  const {route} = useRouter()
  return (
      <Layout>
        <Component {...pageProps} key={route} />
      </Layout>
  );
}
export default MyApp
```

The `CSS` file can be left as is.

Also to keep in mind that because on most mobile there will be a native route loading animation that `NProgress` won't be able to override by itself.